# Ajax Method without XMLHttpRequest() Object

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I have one query about Ajax methodology. I am used to work with ajax like i use four simple lines written below:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/application/group/addMembers",
            data: {memberIds: selectedMembers, groupId:<?php echo $this->groupId; ?>},
            success: (function(msg) {
              // alert(msg);
                var ans = JSON.parse(msg);
                alert(ans['message']); // msg is array returned from php script in json
            })
        });
```

Now, When i study more on different sites or tutorials. They do ajax by creating XMLHTMLREQUEST(), which is used to exchange information with server. And some more things like open, send functions.

But i don't create XMLHTMLREQUEST object and my ajax still works fine. I just want to know the difference. Do i lose something when i don't communicate with server using XMLHTMLREQUEST object. I did search on it. But i still need an answer.

Comment: jQuery does all that for you.

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` is native, pure javascript. jQuery abstracts that and gives you a simpler syntax to work with. But jQuery does use `XMLHttpRequest` behind the scenes.

Comment: What your code does is just creating XmlHTTPRequest under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

the difference between your four simple line and XMLHttpRequest() is the language  itself where XMLHttpRequest() is pure **javascript** while your code above is **jquery**.
infact you could ignore both and use [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) & [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) as they are higher-level alternatives and easier to use. If less common options are required, though, $.ajax() can be used more flexibly.

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers implement AJAX differently (Actually only IE really). jQuery handles all of the cross-browser implementation differences and creates the XHR object in the background.

[From jQuery Source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/xhr.js):

```
jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr = function() {
    try {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch( e ) {}
};

var xhrSupported = jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr(),
    xhrSuccessStatus = {
        // file protocol always yields status code 0, assume 200
        0: 200,
        // Support: IE9
        // #1450: sometimes IE returns 1223 when it should be 204
        1223: 204
    },
    // Support: IE9
    // We need to keep track of outbound xhr and abort them manually
    // because IE is not smart enough to do it all by itself
    xhrId = 0,
    xhrCallbacks = {};

if ( window.ActiveXObject ) {
    jQuery( window ).on( "unload", function() {
        for( var key in xhrCallbacks ) {
            xhrCallbacks[ key ]();
        }
        xhrCallbacks = undefined;
    });
}

jQuery.support.cors = !!xhrSupported && ( "withCredentials" in xhrSupported );
jQuery.support.ajax = xhrSupported = !!xhrSupported;
```

Comment: It means, there is chance for a issue of cross browser differences to come when we create XMLHttpRequest() by ourselves instead of implementing through jquery. Am I right?

Comment: @SherazAli yes. If you are new to AJAX and cross-browser development, there is a potential to have issues. Unless you have VERY SERIOUS concerns about load times, you should be using a library such as jQuery in your application. Even if load times are an issue, using a CDN such as Google should resolve that.